# Function undefined in blazor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm using Blazor WASM with JavaScript for Web API. I have this error:

> Error: Could not find 'AddDb' ('AddDb' was undefined).

**JavaScript**

```
export function AddDB() {
const DB_NAME = 'product';
const DB_VERSION = 1; // Use a long long for this value (don't use a float)
const DB_STORE_NAME = 'MHCproduct';

var db;

// Used to keep track of which view is displayed to avoid uselessly reloading it
var current_view_pub_key;

function openDb() {
    console.log("openDb ...");
    var req = indexedDB.open(DB_NAME, DB_VERSION);
  }
  }
```

**Razor page**

```
 <div class="row">
    <span class="cuscol-100" style="text-align:center;background-color:white">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100%" @onclick="()=>StartDB(elementX)">Calculate</button>
    </span>
</div>

@code{
    string name = string.Empty;
    IJSObjectReference module;

    private ElementReference elementX;

    async Task StartDB(ElementReference element)
    {
        module = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./js/JavaScript.js");
        await module.InvokeVoidAsync("AddDb", element);
        Console.WriteLine("Berjaya");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn´t work with JSInterop for a longer time now, but is it possible that the error occurs because you enter a parameter even though the JS function does not need one?
Can´t check it right now, but maybe change `await module.InvokeVoidAsync("AddDb", element);` to `await module.InvokeVoidAsync("AddDb");`.

Other possible solution: Did you add a `<script src="xyz.js"></script>` to your index.html file?

Answer (score 1):

Just stumble on similar issue. Not sure what resolve it, but I do this to resolve the issue:

*On your Solution Explorer in Visual Studio: Right click the solution and choose clean solution.*

Similar problem from this link: [Blazor Component Javascript Errors (Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67991690/blazor-component-javascript-errors-microsoft-jsinterop-jsexception)